# Why is $1 + i c^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}$ invertible?

Tags: c-star-algebras

I am reading a proof of  this theorem:

If $a,b$ are positive elements of a $C^\ast$ algebra and $a \le b$ then $a^{1/2}\le b^{1/2}$.

I don't understand one step in the proof. I understand this: Let $t > 0$ and $c,d$ be such that $c + i d = (t + b + a)(t + b - a)$. Then $c \ge t^2$ therefore $c$ is positive and invertible.

Given this, why is $1 + i c^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}$ invertible?

Comment: I have a feeling that you can show that $\|c^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}\|<1$ which would ensure that what you have is invertible.

Comment: It was my first thought but I didn't see how to do it.

Comment: Well we know that $\|c^{-1}\|\le t^{-2}$. If you can show that $\|d\| < t^2$, you'd be good to go.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes I know. I have of course thought of that, too. But again I didn't see how to do it. So if you know how to prove it please post an answer, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the argument:

Since $d$ is selfadjoint, so is $c^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}$. Then the spectrum of $1+ic^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}$ is of the form
$$
\{1+i\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(c^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2})\}.
$$
The $\lambda$ are real, so the spectrum does not contain $0$, and thus $1+ic^{-1/2}dc^{-1/2}$ is invertible.

As this equals $c^{-1/2}(c+id)c^{-1/2}$ we conclude that $c+id$ is invertible. Now one can conclude that $t+b-a$ is invertible. As this happens for all $t>0$, $b-a\geq0$, i.e. $a\leq b$.

Comment: This is putting the cart before the horse. You use the fact in OP's statement to prove that $t+b+a$ and $t+b-a$ are invertible...

Comment: What do you mean? I haven't seen the rest of the proof the OP mentions, but the assumption seems to be $0\leq a\leq b$.

Comment: In the proof, you use the fact that $c+id$ is invertible to show that $t+b+a$ is invertible. It can be found in Murphy.

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much. It really seems easy after reading your answer! The book is really weird, it argues the other way around: it states because the LHS of your second displaystyle equation is invertible it follows that the RHS is also invertible and since $c$ is invertible therefore $c + id$. But I think that's purposefully obscurely written and your argument is much better.

Comment: @student: Cameron is right. The proof in Murphy tries to show that $a^2\leq b^2$ implies $a\leq b$. So my argument does not apply to that proof. Please Unaccept so that I can delete the answer.

Comment: But you showed $c + id$ is invertible. That's all the proof needs. What am I missing?

Comment: Everything. The proof does not assume that $a\leq b$. It assumes that $a^2\leq b^2$. Then you cannot reason as I did.

Comment: Bleh, you're right. I kept looking at the statement of the theorem but really the first line of the proof starts with $a^2 \le b^2 $. How annoying. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I got it. Please see the edit.

Comment: Yep! Perfect. I feel so silly. I can't believe I didn't notice that the spectrum basically got bumped off of the real axis.